# React Testing Library leaking between tests, DOM persisting

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to testing and I'm trying to figure out how to reset the DOM after each test to make each an isolated test case.
In the below code I have simply duplicated a test and the first passes but the second fails with the message: `TestingLibraryElementError: Found multiple elements with the placeholder text of: Title`

Therefore the test isn't removing the first instance. Is this normal behaviour? And how do I reset between tests?
I tried using the `cleanup` method as found in the [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react#dom-testing) and [react testing library docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#cleanup), but this doesn't work and according to the docs it should be resetting after each test anyway.

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

import TaskList from './TaskList';

describe('TaskList Component', () => {
  it('Adds a new task when the add button is clicked', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const { getByPlaceholderText, getByAltText } = render(<TaskList />);

    const addButton = getByAltText('add');
    await user.click(addButton);

    expect(getByPlaceholderText('Title')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('Adds a new task when the add button is clicked', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const { getByPlaceholderText, getByAltText } = render(<TaskList />);

    const addButton = getByAltText('add');
    await user.click(addButton);

    expect(getByPlaceholderText('Title')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I'm using the following packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.37",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.6.1",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.9"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleanup is indeed done automatically for Jest + React Testing Library like you mentioned.

Is it possible that TaskList is rendering multiple items with "Title" as their placeholder text? You might be able to find out by using `getAllByPlaceholderText`

Comment: Thanks for your help @bytehala, it was actually due to the reducer used to create the card. This reducer also ran a function to store this new card in local storage and so when run again, the card was first fetched from local storage, hence two cards being created.

Comment: Yeah, as an added tip, you might be able to see what is being rendered by destructuring `const {debug} = render(<MyComponent />)` and then calling `debug()` which prints out the component tree.